# Mendeley can't find "Qt WebEngine Plugins" (desktop app for linux)

Tags: linux, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine, mendeley

I recently upgraded my linux (debian). Since then I Mendeley is not working: it starts and after a couple of seconds starts fetching and crashes immediately.

This is the error message that it is giving:

```
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
```

I tried to uninstall mendeleydesktop and install it again, but still the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like a question for unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: I can tell you that this error message appears even when Mendeley Desktop is running and syncing normally. If you post another question on superuser.com with a fuller list of which version of Debian and Mendeley you are using, and any further error output, I can have a go at troubleshooting it.

Comment: The version 1.17 is not working for me. I installed a previous version (1.16.3) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem on Fedora 25 and Mendeley 1.17 Reverted back to Mendeley 1.16.3 and it works again.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can only find the latest version of Mendeley, any clues where I can get the older version?

Comment: I found in my local folder a copy of an older version of Mendeley and it works. So quite likely there is some bug in the latest version.

Comment: Update: switched to Zotero since Mendeley support for linux is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the same problem.

```
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
Error in finalize query "attempt to write a readonly database" : "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE"
Error in open database "unable to open database file" : "/home/user/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/www.mendeley.com/user@mail.com-f453/search-index.sqlite"
Failed to open search index
Error in prepare query "unable to open database file" : "SELECT value FROM UpdateTokens WHERE key = :key"
Error in bind value "no statement prepared"
Error in execute query "query not prepared"
Error in step query "query not active"
QObject::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
```

The problem, I think, was that the folder where my mendeley database is stored changed its name (don't really know why).
To solve I just erased the folder /home/user/.local/share/Mendeley Ltd. and start mendeleydesktop again so the folder is created again (your papers will have to be sync again).

Comment: I did it and the folder was created again. However it doesn't seem to solve the problem for me.